# Airport transit Visa for Indian

Tags: air-travel, transit, indian-citizens, airport-security, airport-terminals

I am an Indian Citizen, I am travelling from Venezuela to India, I am transiting via Paris(CDG). Do I need to take Airport transit Visa for France or I don't require one.

My friends said these answer,

"None as long as you have the single ticket You will be in transit thru out the journey and you will not do immigration in Paris"

"Actually you don't really need transit Visa in Paris and Amsterdam"

But many people say I need transit Visa, I don´t know what to do. Any information will be highly helpful, thank you!

Comment: The answer is that you do need one, unless you qualify for an exception (point 5 of the accepted answer to the duplicate question). Under point 4, you will see a link to the EU's list, from which it is apparent that Indians do need an airport transit visa (ATV) in France (Paris) but not in the Netherlands (Amsterdam).  From that we can conclude that one of your sources is suspect.  Most countries' nationals don't need an ATV in Paris if they're not clearing immigration, so it's understandable that most people would think you don't need a visa either, but they're likely wrong.